# vb datagrid refresh after updating data in another form

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, datagrid

I have a couple of forms, one without datagrid and one with datagrid. The one without datagrid is for adding values to the database, and that happens. When I come to the page with datagrid, the updated value does not show up. If I see the tableadapter and it has the new values but the datagrid doesn't. I have tried .refresh() which obviously just redraws and un-binded and re-binded the datasource too but that doesn't work either. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You should put your data into something that inherits INotifyPropertyChanged, or create some classes yourself that do this. Since this might be a little complex for you, you can simply refresh the data by clearing and applying the DataSource again.

```
MyGrid.DataSource = Nothing
MyGrid.DataSource = DT
```

*You will need to replace the grid name and DataSource with your variables*

Comment: When I said unbinding and re-binding the DataSource, I meant to have done exactly what you wrote above. It doesn't help me.
Mygrid is datagridview1 and DT is Database1DataSet1.Customers. I replace the same there and run, and it doesn't refresh. Any other options?

Comment: For clarification, I added Datagridview1.DataSource = Nothing and Datagridview1.Datasource = Database1DataSet1.Customers in a refresh button event and not in the Datagrid function call. Should I be doing it there or you were talking about one such refresh button itself?

Comment: Sounds like the 2 datasources are not the same instance. If you declare your datasource in both forms, they are separate instances and you need to use a either a shared instance or when you return from the second form you need to re-query the database for your data.

Comment: Form1 has just a couple of textboxes to update. So I haven't made a datasource, datagrid there. Just run a formal Sql update statement.  (update column1 from Customers where ...). Form2 has datagridview and a DS.